# "unable to find explicit activity" error

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, listview

I'm new in android and I just try to use this code and show the save data on database in listView. but when i press the button say unfortunately has stopped. please help me.

MainActivity Class

```
package com.example.employeedetailsnew;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private EditText nme = null;
private EditText num = null;
private EmployeeDatabase empObj;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    nme = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageemp);
    Button btnShowData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnShowData.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onSaveClick();
        }
    });
}
public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
    if (nme.length()!=0 && num.length()!=0){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
    String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    String varName = nme.getText().toString();
    String varAge = num.getText().toString();
    empObj = new EmployeeDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    empObj.insert(varName,varAge,strDate);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = null;
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.Message));
              alertDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.You_have_been_Registered));
    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
    alertDialog.show();
    nme.setText("");
    num.setText("");
    }else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.Empty_Item),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
public void onSaveClick(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowData.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Detail Class

```
package com.example.employeedetailsnew;

public class DetailClass {
private String name;
private String age;
private String time;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}
}
```

MyAdaptor Class

```
package com.example.employeedetailsnew;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shows_view, parent, false);
    }

    ArrayList times = null;
    DetailClass empDtl = (DetailClass) times.get(index);

    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name1);
    nameTextView.setText(empDtl.getName());


    TextView ageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.age2);
    ageTextView.setText(empDtl.getAge());


    TextView timeTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time3);
    timeTextView.setText((CharSequence) empDtl.getTime());
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name1);
    nameTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));

    TextView ageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name1);
    ageTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("age")));

    TextView timeTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name1);
    timeTextView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time")));
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from (parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shows_list, parent, false);
    return view;
}

}
```

MyDataBase Class

```
package com.example.employeedetailsnew;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

class EmployeeDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

EmployeeDatabase (Context context) {
    super(context, "empdb.db", null,3);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database)
{
    database.execSQL("create table employee" + "(name TEXT , age TEXT, time TEXT)");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EMPLOYEEDETAILNEW");
    onCreate(database);
}

public Cursor getDetails()
{
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery("select rowid _id,name, age,time from employeedetailnew", null);

}
public void insert(String name, String age, String time)
{
    long rowId = 0;
    try{
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);
        contentValues.put("age", age);
        contentValues.put("time", time);
        rowId = db.insert("employeedetailnew", null, contentValues);


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("The rowId is "+rowId);
        System.out.println("Name is "+name);
        System.out.println("Age is "+age);
        System.out.println("Time is "+time);
    }
}
public boolean deleteTitle(String name)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("employeedetailnew", name + "=" + name, null) > 0;
}
}
```

ShowData Class

```
package com.example.employeedetailsnew;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ShowData extends ListActivity


{
private EmployeeDatabase databaseHelper;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.shows_list);


    EmployeeDatabase empClick = new EmployeeDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    Cursor cursor = empClick.getDetails();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String notes = cursor.getString(2);
            String time = cursor.getString(3);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (!cursor.isClosed())
    {
        cursor.close();
    }

}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.employeedetailsnew.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/empname"
    android:layout_below="@+id/empname"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sub"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sub"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"

    android:text="@string/name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/age"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"

    android:text="@string/age" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ageemp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/age"
    android:layout_below="@+id/age"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sub"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
    android:text="@string/sub" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/show_data" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

shows_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

shows_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/age2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and that's my logcat

```
08-16 11:52:08.427  28242-28242/com.example.employeedetailsnew     E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity    class {com.example.employeedetailsnew/com.example.employeedetailsnew.ShowData};    have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
        at com.example.employeedetailsnew.MainActivity.onSaveClick(MainActivity.java:60)
        at com.example.employeedetailsnew.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4421)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17903)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please strip this down to the mimimal amount of code that reproduces your problem... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: why are you extending `CursorAdapter` ? just use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead, also add your Activity to the manifest: `<activity
 android:name=".ShowData"/>`

Comment: @pskink i do it but still say unfortunately has stopped

Comment: try changing the id of the listview from
     `@+id/list_view`  to
     `@android:id/list`

Comment: thank you @Bhargav but no things change

Comment: `ArrayList times = null;
DetailClass empDtl = (DetailClass) times.get(index);` Why are you assigning times = null then invoking .get() fucntion on it?

Answer (score 2):

add `ShowData` Activity in `manifest.xml`

```
<activity
 android:name=".ShowDatata"/>
```

Comment: yeah i forget do this work thanks i do it and refresh my logcat

Comment: @Setare This is a Q&A site. Do not change your question after you've got an answer.